# Google::Apis::RateLimitError: userRateLimitExceeded: User Rate Limit Exceeded. Rate of requests for user exceed configured project quota

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-sheets-api, google-api-client

Currently I am working on rails application in which I have 3 models as follows:

School, Classroom, Section,

One school has many classrooms and every classroom has many sections. Actually right now I have one scenario in which 1 school which has 16 classrooms and each classroom has around 26 sections, so In total I have around 416 records

I need to create spreadsheet for each classroom and every classroom's spreadsheet has 26 worksheets and every worksheet has header on google drive via [api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) for the multiple

I am creating all this with the help of Sidekiq worker using **perform_async** method.

This worked fine for small data samples(say 5 classrooms and each classroom with 3 sections) but when there was huge data,I got the below error:

```
WARN: Google::Apis::RateLimitError: userRateLimitExceeded: User Rate Limit Exceeded. Rate of requests for user exceed configured project quota. You may consider re-evaluating expected per-user traffic to the API and adjust project quota limits accordingly. You may monitor aggregate quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/quotas?project=864617607794
```

I recently increased my limit on google console but still I am getting the same issue.

Can anyone help me out with this issue.

Comment: Not yet. Since you don't provide any indication of quote you are using. You probably need to cache values from a request instead of constantly requesting the current status.

Comment: Google API usually says there is a quota per 100 second per user, But I think they have a implicit limit of 10 calls per second per user (Analytics API documentation) mentions this. 
Had same problem in our project, the workaround we added for this one is to add exponential retry.